# not able to get value from aspx page to aspx.cs

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, function

This is my javascript function where value comes from other page and it is received perfectly, but How can i retrieve "**divConversation**" value in cs page  .
This is my code

```
 function myLoad() {

        document.getElementById('divConversation').innerText = getParameterByName("id");


    }
```

Comment: Your div needs to be with runat=server attribute. then you can access it from the server side

Comment: @codeSpy I have tried using hiddenfield, but problem remains same, How do i get the value of hiddenfield from aspx page to aspx.cs page???

Comment: @codeSpy Please paste the full code, because its not working, in any way i tried, it will be a great help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Main Problem With Your Requirement is that the server side code is executed first, So what you need is to receive the passed value on page_load instead of receiving on aspx page.

And this can be done by

```
String passedValue=Request.QueryString["id"] as string;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a really simple demonstration:

aspx/markup; this will set the value of your hidden field as you type

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

    <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server" />
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
</div>
</form>
<script>
    document.getElementById('<%= TextBox1.UniqueID %>').onkeyup = function (evt) {
        document.getElementById('<%= HiddenField1.UniqueID %>').value = document.getElementById('<%= TextBox1.UniqueID %>').value;
    }
</script>
```

Code behind (.cs)

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Write(HiddenField1.Value);
}
```

Comment: But i may need casting here

Comment: document.getElementById('<%= HiddenField1.UniqueID %>').value =getParameterByName("id");
or                                                                           
document.getElementById('<%= HiddenField1.clienID %>').value =getParameterByName("id");
or something else??